# Standard Interface to Interact with Various Content Repositories From J2EE Client Server Environment Using JCR

Tags: java, alfresco, jackrabbit, jcr, content-repository

I have an existing Java Web application which uses ***alfresco*** as its content repository.
Now I want my application to have a content repository interface to interact not only with alfresco but also with any JCR compliant repositories(Even to a local file system). According to my application architecture we can Inject JCR Implementation of any content repositories. I googled a lot and couldnt find any useful step by step walk guide to implement **JCR** Interface and Injecting an implementation. Please provide some links or something with which i can establish this easily. Atleast I want to use JCR alfresco Implementation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using CMIS? CMIS has much wider support on both the server and client side

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CMIS + Apache Chemistry and do the switch!

Answer (score 0):

Well with JCR 2.0 the [RepositoryFactory](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/RepositoryFactory.html) should be able to provide you with the repository you want. After that it is just how to pass the configuration in your code to create and access the repository.
You can look into [Silverpeas](https://github.com/Silverpeas) code or [Crash](http://www.crashub.org/)'s code to see that.